# I want to leave a group chat in Facebook but I keep getting added back

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I want to leave a group chat on Facebook but every time I do the members of the chat add me right back. How can I prevent them from adding me back?

Comment: From what I recall there's a checkbox to "prevent being added again" when you leave a conversation. I don't have access to my desktop right now to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

For Facebook groups:
When leaving, before confirming, there is a small box

```
prevent other users from adding you again.
```

**Check** that box.

For chat groups you cannot do that.
If it happens to be the same user every time, unfriend, or block, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can only prevent being re-added to groups.  Not for chats.